# Prove that $int(A) = (cl(A^c))^c$

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that $int(A) =  (cl(A^c))^c$

I draw some diagrams to get the intuition for this exercise but couldn't figure out how to formulate this into a proof.

I'd be glad for a guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Another one here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203001/the-interior-is-the-complement-of-the-closure-of-the-complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$cl(A^c)$ is a closed which contains $A^c$, thus $cl(A^c)^c$ is an open subset contained in $(A^c)^c=A$ thus $cl(A^c)^c$ is contained in $int(A)$.

On the other hand, let $U\subset A$ be an open subset, $U^c$ is a closed subset which contains $A^c$ thus it contains $cl(A^c)$ this implies that $(U^c)^c=U\subset cl(A^c)^c$. done

Comment: Why is it sufficient to show it for $U\subset A$?

Comment: I show that $int(A)=cl(A^c)^c$ by showing that $cl(A^c)^c\subset int(A)$ and $int(A)\subset cl(A^c)^c$. The proof of the second part starts with $U\subset A$ an open subset it is enough to show that $U\subset cl(A^c)^c$ since $int(A)$ is the union of the open subsets contained in $A$.